# Merge Semantic UI React Input with Masked React Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Anyone know the best way to merge two react input components? Preferably as it relates to [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction) and [react-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-mask). Here's what I've got so far (I've been unable to pass down props to the masked child component):

```
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import MaskedInput from "react-text-mask";

const CustomInput = () => (
  <div>
    <Input focus placeholder="Search...">
      <MaskedInput
        mask={[
          "(",
          /[1-9]/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
          ")",
          " ",
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
          "-",
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/
        ]}
        guide={true}
      />
    </Input>
  </div>
);

export default CustomInput;
```

Comment: Which is your masked child component? Are you trying to pass props to your `CustomInput`?

Comment: Eventually I plan to pass props. Maybe I misunderstand your other question, but the MaskedInput component (provided by react-text-mask) is the child of Input (provided by semantic-ui). I've tried switching the parent/child relationship without success.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass all props to the child using

```
{...this.props}
```

in your case just pass the "Input's" props to the "MaskedInput"  like

```
<Input focus placeholder="Search...">
  <MaskedInput
    mask={["(",/[1-9]/,/\d/,/\d/,")"," ",/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,"-",/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,/\d/]}  
    guide={true} {...this.props} />
</Input>
```

Comment: My understanding is that passing those props down without a filter is dangerous - will likely result in warnings especially for custom props. My current solution passes the props, but filters using valid proptypes. But, it doesn't seem like a great solution.